# Pyarrow flight server to expose custom endpoints

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow-flight

Can i create a pyarrow flight server that can expose custom end points which the client can call ?
I have seen only code where do_get method returning pyarrow tables.
Can the client pass on parameters that can be used to filter the data on the server side and return the filtered arrow table ?

Please can you help with some sample code